# How to consume an rss feed under a specific account

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following requirement.
I have a sharepoint 2013 which is internal to our network, and needs to expose some rss feeds.

I found the perfect way to do it with this blog post.
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/search-based-rss-sharepoint-2013/

However, we need to develop an external app that will show data from several sources, one its our internal sharepoint site.

How can I consume this rss feed with asp.net UNDER A SPECIFIC ACCOUNT
Sharepoint will render the data based on the account used to consume it.

Comment: what do you mean by under a specific account?

Comment: yes, the consumption of the rss feed should be done under a specific login/passsword from the internal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is an network access from external application to the SharePoint RSS feed.

The simplest way would be to use WebRequest class. This class exposes the Cridentials property. You can set this properties  by instantiating NetworkCredential class,

```
ex: new NetworkCredential( "username", "password", "domain" )
```